# How can I find flathead screws with the correct head diameter?

Tags: screws

I have a door that uses these screws to hold the handles on. At some point in the past, some of the screws fell out and were replaced with screws that have slightly smaller heads, which means the handles fall off because they get pulled past the head of the screw.

The top screw in the picture is the correct screw, and the bottom one is wrong.

[image: screws]

I have measured the screws, but they don't seem to match either a standard US size or metric size. (I am in the US, but the hardware is from a German company.)

- Length: 30mm / 1.18 in.
- Major Diameter: 4.3mm / 0.17 in.
- Head diameter (bad screw): 8mm / 0.325. in.
- Head diameter (good screw): 8.75mm / 0.345 in.

The weird part is that the length is perfect in mm but the diameters are perfect US fractions (11/64, 5/16, and 11/32 respectively).

How can I find the correct size of screw to use here?

Comment: is the door wood? if so you could stick a toothpick in before putting the screw back in

Comment: Usually wood screw sizes are given by numbers and length.  Without knowing the size from the picture, might say they #8 or #10 size.  Should be able to google screw sizes.

Comment: @crip659 The measurements I have are closest to #9, which is not available in most hardware stores, and is still not quite right.

Comment: Unless the clearance hole is a machine fit, then a #10 screw should fit

Comment: McMaster-Carr catalog provides several options. When I need to find weird hardware I look there first. Not usually cheapest, (or in this case, you'll probably have to buy 100 from them)  but a very broad selection. And a good parametric search.

Comment: Those look the same to me. *Toothpick in the wood door* isn't going to help. The prob is the deformed hole(s) in the metal escutcheon (I think if you put the top one in the bottom you'd have the same prob in reverse). They don't *have* to be flat head. Put some clunky pan heads in there and make it work. Don't strip the phillips head any, or they'll be sharp. And do not use screw guns on door hardware.

Comment: @Mazura They looked the same to me at first glance, but the calipers don't lie - they are just different enough (0.75mm) that the smaller one passes through the hole and the larger one doesn't. Also, they *do* have to be flat head because there is a plastic trim that covers where they sit.

Answer (score 5):

I'll suggest going about this in a different way.

Because these flat-head wood screws go into wood, the screw size (thread pitch, diameter, length) don't have to exactly match the original fasteners.

Go to the hardware store, and find flat-head wood screws with heads large enough to fit correctly in the handle hardware (that is, the screw heads won't pull through), and whose length and diameter is about the same as the original screws. Exact duplicates of the original screws aren't necessary.

If the new screws don't tighten down into the holes firmly, remove the new screws, partially fill each screw hole with segments of a hardwood toothpick, and replace the screws. A little wood glue into the hole will help hold the toothpick segments in place.

Comment: Wood glue along with the toothpicks is often recommended. Helps hold the toothpicks in place should the screw need to be removed again in the future.

Comment: @FreeMan Good call, thanks, I added it to the answer.